# I want to add css class to a field inside hook_field_widget_form_alter, but it doesn't work!

Tags: hooks, entities

in this link
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7

it describes that we can add css class to an element in a form via this code

```
function hook_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Add a css class to widget form elements for all fields of type mytype.
  if ($context['field']['type'] == 'mytype') {
    // Be sure not to overwrite existing attributes.
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
  }
}
```

I tried to use it but it seems `$element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';` doesn't add any css class to form after rendering.

So how can I add css class to a form element inside [`hook_field_widget_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) ?

Comment: you should  use the development module to find out with $element  you have to use

Answer (score 0):

Old issue but it might help future viewers.
Try this:
`$element['value']['#attributes']['class'] = 'myclass';`

See `field_multiple_value_form()` which creates the render array.
Then main theme function for rendering fields in forms is `theme_field_multiple_value_form()` and the parent theme function is `theme_form_element()`